# Importance of .classpath when generating war file & running war file in WAS for Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse

We edit the `.classpath` file when order of import is changed or new lib is added to build path.
We are generating the war using `Eclipse's Export --> war` option.
But war does not have `.classpath` file after it is exported.
Will the parameters of `.classpath` affect the execution of the war in WAS.

Answer (score 2):

No. The .classpath file is purely a Eclipse thing, it is not relevant for execution of a JAR, WAR or EAR file. The relevant information is compiled into the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF of the WAR file.

(On a side note, I suggest using a build system like Maven or Gradle, which will manage the classpath for you, among other things. Building the WAR manually through Eclipse is error-prone and should be avoided for production.)